# Why aren't the variables being updated when I trigger an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, switch-statement, var

I'm quite new to programming so it would be nice to get some help.

Why isn't the variables updating when i push the button??

html:

```
    <h1>NIM</h1>
    <p>Welcome to a simple edition of the game NIM</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>You</th>
            <th>Left</th>
            <th>PC</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p id="pl" class="nr">0</p></td>
            <td><p id="a" class="nr">25</p></td>
            <td><p id="pc" class="nr">0</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <br>
    <p>How many do you want to pull?</p>
    <input type="number" id="val" value="1" min="1" max="3">
    <button id="turn">Trekk</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#turn').click(function () {
var val    = parseInt($('#val').val()),
    player = parseInt($('#pl').html()),
    pc     = parseInt($('#pc').html()),
    total  = parseInt($('#a').html());
console.log(val);
console.log(total);

do {
    switch (val) {
    case 1:
        total -= 4;
        player += 1;
        pc += 3;
        break;
    case 'b2':
        total -= 4;
        player += 2;
        pc += 2;
        break;
    case 'b3':
        total -= 4;
        player += 3;
        pc += 1;
        break;
    }

} while (total > 1);});
```

I'm probably more familiar with c++, this is the first time i try a do loop in javascript/jquery.

Comment: Is that code executing?

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rudauke/ssw9w230/) here, the variables are being updated. The text is not updated, but that's because you don't update it anywhere

Comment: your code is working. the variables change. use `console.log()` after the `do` loop

Comment: Will you accept the answer or react to it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the game you were trying to make. Enjoy it!

```
<html> 

<head> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var val    = 0; //Initial value of the input box 
    var player = parseInt($('#pl').html()); //Player score
    var pc     = parseInt($('#pc').html()); //pc score
    var total  = parseInt($('#a').html()); //Total left

    $('#turn').click(function () {

        val = parseInt($('#val').val());

        console.log(val);
        console.log(total);

        if(total > 0){

            switch (val) {
            case 1:
                total -= 4;
                player += 1;
                pc += 3;
                break;
            case 2:
                total -= 4;
                player += 2;
                pc += 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                total -= 4;
                player += 3;
                pc += 1;
                break;
            }

            $('#pl').html(player);
            $('#pc').html(pc);
            $('#a').html(total);
        }
    });

});

</script>

</head> 

<body> 

    <h1>NIM</h1>
    <p>Welcome to a simple edition of the game NIM</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>You</th>
            <th>Left</th>
            <th>PC</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p id="pl">0</p></td>
            <td><p id="a">25</p></td>
            <td><p id="pc">0</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <br>
    <p>How many do you want to pull?</p>
    <input type="number" id="val" value="1" min="1" max="3">
    <button id="turn">Trekk</button>

</body> 

</html>
```

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/1o6qxw9c/

**Your Mistakes**

1. You cannot use '$' directly like this. Include jQuery.
2. Initiate the value of *val* by '0'.
3. You need to update only val and calculate rest of the things based on first time fetching values. If you write all code on click of button -- all others values will also be reset.
4. Wrap all code in document.ready() for them to work properly.
5. You need to update the values back of Total, pc, and player score once calculated which you missed out.

> JavaScript is different than 'C'. Congrats for making in to the language of the web, as JS is used both on client and server side. Try hard, first learn simple basic operations, then move after an year to understand OOJS. Though, it provides glorious features, but if not understood well, then most of the time you will remain confused of the results that popup!